# How do I make Grails 2.3.1 notice changes to BuildConfig.groovy?

Tags: grails

I've got a Grails 2.3.1 project that compiles and runs fine. But when I add or remove dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy` (and then run `grails clean`, `grails refresh-dependencies`), the framework simply doesn't notice my changes.

If I introduce a syntax error, my code fails to compile. But my (syntactically valid) changes never even show up in `grails dependency-report`.

I can "fix" things via `rm -rf ~/.grails/2.3.1/projects/myproject`.

But that is terrible.

What's the right way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it work if you run `grails compile` instead of `clean` and `refresh-dependencies`? If not, and you can create a small app that demonstrates this behavior, run `grails bug-report` and attach that ZIP to an issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

Comment: I will report -- but first, just want to check: while I'm in the grails CLI,  if I separately edit `BuildConfig.groovy` to add a dependency on something nonexistent, and then I `compile` + `refresh-dependencies`, that should throw an error, right?

Comment: Yes, it will show an error, and there will be more useful info if you set the `log` attribute to `warn`. Note that you should do this outside of the interactive console (i.e. when you just run `grails`) since that more for running the app and tests. But changes like this should be done directly from the commandline.

Comment: Ahh. I was trying to run `refresh-dependencies` from the console (which it was happy to let me try to do). Is this wisdom ("changes.. should be done directly from the commandline") documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try `grails clean-all` instead. The regular `clean` command is not going to clean all files...